# On the equation $a^n + b^n = c^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am interested in the possible natural solutions of the equation $a^n + b^n = c^2$ where $n \geq 4$ is fixed. I am not sure if it is  well-known or not,  so any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: A related problem is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%E2%80%93Catalan_conjecture

Answer (score 12):

To complement Boris Novikov's answer, Darmon and Merel have shown that the equation has no solution with $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. See J. reine angew. Math. 490 (1997), 81-100.

Answer (score 9):

$2^{2n+1}+2^{2n+1}=( 2^{n+1})^2$.

Comment: a solution when the exponent in the problem is odd.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: More generally, choose arbitrary $p$ and $q$.  Set $r=p^{2n+1}+q^{2n+1}$.  Then $a=pr$, $b=qr$ and $c=r^{n+1}$ gives a solution for exponent $2n+1$.

Comment: @Carl: It is nice!

Comment: Even exponent is ruled out by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_descent#Non-solvability_of_r2_.2B_s4_.3D_t4 except the trivial $0^n+1^n=1^2$.

Comment: @Boris: rino meant that in your example the exponents on the left hand side are odd. As Carl mentioned, there is no example with even exponents.

Comment: @GH from MO: Yes, of course. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $gcd(a,b,c)=1$ there are no solutions (see GH's answer), and this fits well for the hyperbolic case of the generalised Fermat equation 
 $x^p+y^q=z^r$ with
$1/p+1/q+1/r<1$, and $gcd(x,y,z)=1$, because for $n>4$ above we are in this case. 
By Darmon-Granville theorem we know that there are only finitely many solutions, and conjecturally at most $10$ solutions. None of these is for $(p,q,r)=(n,n,2)$ with $n>4$.